# Is there any other way to place "Close Tooltip" to default close button in the panel header in extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs5

I am using extjs for my project. There is a default close button on the upper right side for every panel. I am able to put tooltip for the button using its position.

```
function closeTooltip (window, 1) {
    Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
        target: window.header.items.get(1).el,
        html: 'Close'
      });
```

But, this isn't so cool because, if I add a button to the header then the position of the close button changes from 1 to 2. So, the tooltip gets displayed for the newly added button.

Is there any other way to keep close tooltip to close button that remains same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting your `close` button, you can use [`down`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-down) method of [Ext.dom.Element](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element).

The `down` method selects a single child at any depth below this element based on the passed `CSS` selector (the selector should not contain an id).

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2e4n)**, I have created a demo using `panel`. I have tested in ExtJS 4.x and later versions, it's working fine. I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        function closeTooltip(panel) {
            if (Ext.getVersion().major > 5) {
                Ext.getCmp(panel.el.down('.x-tool-close').up().id).setTooltip('close')
            } else {
                Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
                    target: panel.el.down('.x-tool-close').id,
                    html: ' Close '
                    //If you want to put diffrent-diffrent tooll tip then you can use below
                    //html:`Close ${panel.title}`
                });
            }
        }

        Ext.define('CustomPanel', {
            extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
            width: 200,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            margin: 5,
            html: 'Custom panel used',
            closable: true,
            tools: [{
                type: 'help',
                handler: function () {
                    alert('help');
                }
            }],
            listeners: {
                afterrender: closeTooltip
            }
        });

        Ext.create('CustomPanel', {
            title: 'Panel 1',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });

        Ext.create('CustomPanel', {
            title: 'Panel 2',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });

        Ext.create('CustomPanel', {
            title: 'Panel 3',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });

        Ext.create('CustomPanel', {
            title: 'Panel 4',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
        Ext.create('CustomPanel', {
            title: 'Panel 4',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. But randomly the tooltip is getting displayed for 2 times if i point my mouse pointer on the button.

Comment: I have checked, In my `Chrome` and `Mozilla` it's working fine. Please let me know for which version your are checking ?

Comment: I'm using v5.1.1.

Comment: @DivakarArasu yes I have checked in v5.1.1 as well it's working fine.. Can you please provide the screenshot of issue and also let me know which browser you are using with version ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/49P1Qk4 here is the image and im using Google Chrome Version 64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Please see this screen shot https://imgur.com/NXC837C. I need to check your code. My Google Chrome Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit).
Please provide your change password code..

Comment: oops I'm new to stackoverflow. Thanks for the info. Did it.